# Reindex multiple indexes in postgresql in one query

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

I can reindex indexes one by one like this:

```
database=# REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY indexname1;
...
database=# REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY indexname2;
...
```

How could I run reindex of multiple indexes in one query?

Something like this:

```
database=# REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY indexname1 indexname2;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "indexname2"
LINE 1: REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY indexname1 indexname2;
                                                    ^
```

Or this:

```
database=# REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY indexname_*
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "*"
LINE 1: REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY indexname_*
                                             ^
```

Comment: The docs are pretty clear I think: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation, REINDEX cannot be executed inside a transaction block when used with a partitioned table, schema, or database. This means that you cannot use a single transaction to REINDEX multiple items concurrently.

You can execute multiple REINDEX CONCURRENTLY commands in a single script, through a python interface with PostgreSQL with psycopg2.

```
import psycopg2

index_list = ['indexname1', 'indexname2']

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="your_db_name", user="your_username", password="your_password", host="your_host", port="your_port")

cur = conn.cursor()

for index in index_list:
    cur.execute(f"REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY {index};")

conn.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this solution, although it is certainly not suitable in every case:

since my end goal was to perform `REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY indexname` on all indexes in the database, the sum of all `REINDEX INDEX ...` comes down to running a single `REINDEX DATABASE CONCURRENTLY dbname` query.

**Warning:** use this only if you understand how many indexes there are in your database, what their size is, how long such `REINDEX DATABASE` might take to complete and how much additional load it might create on the server.